# Is the following a well-known idiom? "The legal team buried them in paper"

Tags: idioms, legalese

Slang Legal Terms
I have heard the expression in movies but  it is not represented as an idiom in computer searches.
I want to use it in a legal case in which I am involved
A similar question occurs in another posting.

Comment: "Buried in paper" is certainly a recognized idiom in US business English, and an easily understood analogy even if the idiom is not recognized.  (And, for that matter, I can recall a couple of cases where the meaning was literal, though the situation was the victims' own doing.)

Comment: In fact, some writers use the more elaborate form, "buried in an avalanche of paper," presumably playing on the whiteness of paper and the whiteness of snow.

Comment: My mom was a secretary, and she used to use this all the time. "I'm so buried in paperwork I can't even find my desk!!"

Answer (score 1):

The idiom, *to bury oneself in something*, is recognized by the [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buried).

Definition:

> 1. Figurative: to become very busy with something.

Example:

> She stopped taking phone calls and *buried herself in her work*.

This idiom is also recognized by:

- [Cambridge Advanced Learner’s Dictionary & Thesaurus](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bury-yourself-in-sth)
- [Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bury)
- [Macmillan Dictionary Online](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bury-yourself-in-something)
- [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bury?q=bury%20oneself#bury__14)

Comment: Note that "buried in paper" has a connotation somewhat different from "buried in his/her work".  The former usually suggests that the "paper" is coming from an outside source, whereas the latter tends to imply that the individual has, as it were, "burrowed into" the work somewhat voluntarily.

Comment: True. The example sentence is from the website.

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer the term *paperwork* in either the passive or active voice, but *paper* would also work.

1. The legal team was buried in paperwork
2. The legal team buried the defendant in paperwork

Alternatively, one could use the participle *drowning*, as in "He was drowning in paperwork". Merriam-Webster calls this construction a metaphor

> [**“He was drowning in paperwork”**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphor) is a metaphor in which having to deal with a lot of paperwork is being compared to drowning in an ocean of water.

You can certainly be *buried*...

1. *in* paperwork

[image]

2. *under a pile of* paper (OR) documents

[image]

[Source](http://edsonphotographyclub.com/buried-under-the-paperwork/)

3. *under a mountain of* paper/paperwork

[image]

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drowning%20in%20paperwork%2Cburied%20in%20paperwork%2Ca%20mountain%20of%20paperwork&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrowning%20in%20paperwork%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cburied%20in%20paperwork%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20mountain%20of%20paperwork%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdrowning%20in%20paperwork%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cburied%20in%20paperwork%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20mountain%20of%20paperwork%3B%2Cc1) suggests “a mountain of paperwork” (green line) is the most common phrase.

[image]

Comment: Downvoted for showing the different variants and for pointing out the noun "paperwork" is often used